# Chrome crashes when I try to add user account

Tags: google-chrome, browser

My Google Chrome (Version 55.0.2862.1 ) crashes every time when I try to login  into a Google account by clicking on the Person icon present on the top right corner. I want to sync my settings and bookmarks from previous installation of chrome but am unable to do so.

Troubleshooting steps I have carried out - (None of them worked)

- Update Chrome
- Delete Chrome app data
- Install Chromium

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue with the latest version in 2020.